# Iterator in not generating list correctly

Tags: python

Why this code is returning [[2, 3]] instead of [[1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 6], [3, 6, 9]] ?

```
i = (i for i in range(1, 4))
l = [[x * y for y in i] for x in i]
print(l)
```

Comment: Your `i` is a generator expression, so it becomes exhausted the first time through.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`i` is generator object, which means the values in it are consumed after the first iteration. In `[[x * y for y in i] for x in i]` you iterate over it twice, in the seconed time its empty. You can change `i` to list instead

```
i = [i for i in range(1, 4)]
l = [[x * y for y in i] for x in i]
print(l)
# output [[1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 6], [3, 6, 9]]
```

Answer (score 2):

As already noted you created `i` which is exhaustable, I suggest different fix: just use `range` directly i.e:

```
i = range(1, 4)
l = [[x * y for y in i] for x in i]
print(l)
```

output:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 6], [3, 6, 9]]
```

call to `range` does create instance of `class` `range` which might be used multiple times for example

```
x = range(1,4)
print(list(x))
print(list(x))
print(list(x))
```

output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
```